# How to use javascript confirm in codeigniter controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I want to make a confirm box in controller (CI). How should i do that? I know to write javascript confirm in view.php file but for now i have sessions and validate to null or valid at the last submit form on click submit button. So, I need to make confirm dialog into CI Controller function. Please help me.

Here is my view code.

```
<div align="center" class="col-md-9" id="label">
   <form method="post" id="formsubmit1" name="formsubmit1" action="{base_url('home/completionform')}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="form_block">       
        <p class="question">
        You can now submit that you answered above or you can continue to answer next questions.
        </p>
           <br>
             <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default nextbutton" id="btn_submit" value="Submit" onclick="completionform();" />
        <a href="{base_url('home/question5')}" class="btn btn-default">Continue</a>
     </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my submit completion form controller function code.

```
public function completionform()
{

    $sess_data=$this->session->userdata();
    $ses_key = key($sess_data);
    if (empty($sess_data['user_info']))
    {
        echo "Session has been destroyed~!";
    }
    else
    {
        $user_info = ($sess_data['user_info']);

        if (!empty($sess_data['question5']))
        {
            $q1 = ($sess_data['question1']);
            $q2 = ($sess_data['question2']);
            $q3 = ($sess_data['question3']);
            $q4 = ($sess_data['question4']);
            $q5 = ($sess_data['question5']);
            $q6 = ($sess_data['question6']);
            $q7 = ($sess_data['question7']);
        }
        else
        {
            $q1 = ($sess_data['question1']);
            $q2 = ($sess_data['question2']);
            $q3 = ($sess_data['question3']);
            $q4 = ($sess_data['question4']);
        }


        $username = '';
        $email = '';
        $phone = '';

        $answer1 = '';
        $answer2 = '';
        $answer3 = '';
        $answer4 = '';
        $answer5 = '';
        $answer6 = '';
        $answer7 = '';

        if (!empty($sess_data['question5']))
        {
            for ($i = 0; $i <  count($user_info); $i++)
            {
                $key=key($user_info);
                $val=$user_info[$key];
                if ($val<> ' ')
                {
                    if ($key === 'name')
                    {
                        $username = $val;
                        //echo $result1;
                    }
                    else if ($key === 'phone')
                    {
                        $phone = $val;
                        //echo $result2;
                    }
                    else if ($key === 'mail')
                    {
                        $email = $val;
                        //echo $result3;
                    }
                   //echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
                }
                next($user_info);
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i <  count($q1); $i++)
            {
                $key=key($q1);
                $val=$q1[$key];
                if ($val<> ' ')
                {
                    if ($key === 'answer1')
                    {
                        $answer1 = $val;
                        //echo $result1;
                    }
                   //echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
                }
                next($q1);
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i <  count($q2); $i++)
            {
                $key=key($q2);
                $val=$q2[$key];
                if ($val<> ' ')
                {
                    if ($key === 'answer2')
                    {
                        $answer2 = $val;
                        //echo $result1;
                    }
                   //echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
                }
                next($q2);
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i <  count($q3); $i++)
            {
                $key=key($q3);
                $val=$q3[$key];
                if ($val<> ' ')
                {
                    if ($key === 'answer3')
                    {
                        $answer3 = $val;
                        //echo $result1;
                    }
                   //echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
                }
                next($q3);
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i <  count($q4); $i++)
            {
                $key=key($q4);
                $val=$q4[$key];
                if ($val<> ' ')
                {
                    if ($key === 'answer4')
                    {
                        $answer4 = $val;
                        //echo $result1;
                    }
                   //echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
                }
                next($q4);
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i <  count($q5); $i++)
            {
                $key=key($q5);
                $val=$q5[$key];
                if ($val<> ' ')
                {
                    if ($key === 'answer5')
                    {
                        $answer5 = $val;
                        //echo $result1;
                    }
                   //echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
                }
                next($q5);
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i <  count($q6); $i++)
            {
                $key=key($q6);
                $val=$q6[$key];
                if ($val<> ' ')
                {
                    if ($key === 'answer6')
                    {
                        $answer6 = $val;
                        //echo $result1;
                    }
                   //echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
                }
                next($q6);
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i <  count($q7); $i++)
            {
                $key=key($q7);
                $val=$q7[$key];
                if ($val<> ' ')
                {
                    if ($key === 'answer7')
                    {
                        $answer7 = $val;
                        //echo $result1;
                    }
                   //echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
                }
                next($q7);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for ($i = 0; $i <  count($user_info); $i++)
            {
                $key=key($user_info);
                $val=$user_info[$key];
                if ($val<> ' ')
                {
                    if ($key === 'name')
                    {
                        $username = $val;
                        //echo $result1;
                    }
                    else if ($key === 'phone')
                    {
                        $phone = $val;
                        //echo $result2;
                    }
                    else if ($key === 'mail')
                    {
                        $email = $val;
                        //echo $result3;
                    }
                   //echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
                }
                next($user_info);
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i <  count($q1); $i++)
            {
                $key=key($q1);
                $val=$q1[$key];
                if ($val<> ' ')
                {
                    if ($key === 'answer1')
                    {
                        $answer1 = $val;
                        //echo $result1;
                    }
                   //echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
                }
                next($q1);
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i <  count($q2); $i++)
            {
                $key=key($q2);
                $val=$q2[$key];
                if ($val<> ' ')
                {
                    if ($key === 'answer2')
                    {
                        $answer2 = $val;
                        //echo $result1;
                    }
                   //echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
                }
                next($q2);
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i <  count($q3); $i++)
            {
                $key=key($q3);
                $val=$q3[$key];
                if ($val<> ' ')
                {
                    if ($key === 'answer3')
                    {
                        $answer3 = $val;
                        //echo $result1;
                    }
                   //echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
                }
                next($q3);
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i <  count($q4); $i++)
            {
                $key=key($q4);
                $val=$q4[$key];
                if ($val<> ' ')
                {
                    if ($key === 'answer4')
                    {
                        $answer4 = $val;
                        //echo $result1;
                    }
                   //echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
                }
                next($q4);
            }
        }

        $this->load->model('answer_model');
        $this->answer_model->add_data('user_tbl',['U_Id'=>"default",  'User_Name'=>$username, 'Phone_Number'=>$phone, 'Mail_Address'=>$email, 'Answer_1'=>$answer1, 'Answer_2'=>$answer2, 'Answer_3'=>$answer3, 'Answer_4'=>$answer4, 'Answer_5'=>$answer5, 'Answer_6'=>$answer6, 'Answer_7'=>$answer7]);
```

Comment: Show your Controller Code - or @least what you've tried so far, imho you can always use a view or a js file for that no matter what ;)

Comment: I updated my question. Please check my code. In that function have sessions data from whole project and i want to check that session data in that controller and make confirm box to submit or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this in controller function

```
echo "<script language=\"javascript\">confirm('confirm box');</script>";
```

this can help you

```
$this->load->library('session');
$result = $this->your_model->user_ques($question);
if ($result) {

    foreach ($result as $ans)
    {
        $sess_array = array(
            'full_name' => $ans->full_name,
            'catagory' => $ans->catagory,
            );
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
    }
    return TRUE;
```

Comment: but it can't condition to check the sessions data are null or not. thanks